# How to blur a text and make it unreadable programmatically on a web page

Tags: javascript, css

I wanna make something like [this page](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-typeface-similar-to-Gotham-that-is-available-for-use-with-font-face)

Fonts (comments) are blurred and selectable but not pasteable. how to do something like this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Blur effect**, you can do this with css:

```
.textshadow {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/UcSyt/) [Details](http://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/)

The following css to prevent from copying text of web page.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/UcSyt/1/) [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

There is also another way to prevent text from copying:

```
<p onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/LSs2j/)

### Update

[Site Text](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-typeface-similar-to-Gotham-that-is-available-for-use-with-font-face) using **SVG Blur effect**. Here is **[Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example.3A_Blurred_Text)**. This effect does't prevent it from coping text, reason behind you can't copy it because of there are not showing you text but these are blank spaces `&nbsp;` you can see it also using developer tool.

## [FEATURED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/m8G9q/2/)

Comment: but the text can be copied and pasted. i wanna exclude that feature

Comment: thanks it helped a little.... but the thing is not exactly as the page shows.. see, you can only select it (by dragging over) but if u try to ctrl+c and ctrl+v that text it doesn't paste

Comment: not working exactly like that page... it's also preventing form selecting

Comment: drag over the blurred texts... the blue background appears as selected text (blurred)

Comment: what the! the comments/answers were all blurred and was telling me to sign up to see them.. strange!

Comment: @Hanze please see updated answer and don't forget to delete unwanted comments as i read them.